# Error in opening Raster dataset in qgis "Cannot open GDAL Dataset"

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, error

Error in opening Raster dataset in qgis (see image below). Is there any suggestion as to why this is happening? and how do i correct it?

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot the image.

Comment: What sort of *img* file should these files be? Several image formats use the extension *img*, eg. ERDAS, IDRISI or generic image array format

Comment: It gives the same error with .tif files also

Comment: Have you tried to use a shorter path to your file? Try copying it just under D:\ or C:\ in order to get a shorter path. I have already got this kind of problem with long paths... And the error message did not help very much either.

Comment: Can you open any image with your QGIS? If not then probably your QGIS installation is broken.

Comment: I think it was broken....

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this error can occur when QGIS can't add too many files (maybe a working memmory issue). In my case I solved it by adding some of the files (>100 MB hdf files) to a different QGIS project.